# Using non standard declaration of array in C

Tags: c, arrays, gcc

I came across the following code which declares `char *` array in `C` in a non-standard way:

```
    /* Message Type description array */ 
    char *msgType[M_LAST_MSG] = 
    {    
       [M_INIT_MSG]     "Init", 
       [M_RESET_MSG]    "Serdes Reset"
    };
```

`M_INIT_MSG`, `M_RESET_MSG` and `M_LAST_MSG` are enumerations with corresponding values of 0, 1 and 2. 
According to the formal `C` documentations, the variables inside this array are string (literals) so what is the purpose of using those enumerations in that manner and is there any documentation to back it up?

Compiled with ARM `gcc` compiler `gcc-arm-none-eabi`.

Comment: You are probably missing `=` in your initializations: `[M_INIT_MSG]  =  "Init"` etc. Search for *designated initializers*.

Comment: No, I didn't miss it. Answer edited.

Comment: Talking about standard/non-standard and then linking to a gcc extension is probably not a good idea... But what in the linked page is not clear? It is an obsolete gcc extension, did you even read the page? From the page: "_An alternative syntax for this that has been obsolete since GCC 2.5 but GCC still accepts is to write ‘[index]’ before the element value, with no ‘=’._"

Comment: Yes I read it, thank you. This explain my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This syntax allows you to initialize specific elements of an array by index.  You can use either `int` or `enum` values to specify which array element to initialize.  This way, the values you assign don't need to be consecutive.

If for example you had this:

```
int x[5] = { [2] 3, [4] 7 };
```

It would be equivalent to this:

```
int x[5] = { 0, 0, 3, 0, 7 };
```

In the above example, the enum values specify that elements 0 and 1 of the array are initialized to `"Init"` and `"Serdes Reset"`.

From section 6.7.8 of the [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> 18 Each  designator  list  begins  its  description  with  the 
>   current  object  associated  with  the closest  surrounding  brace 
>   pair.  Each  item  in  the  designator  list  (in  order)  specifies 
>   a particular  member  of  its  current  object  and  changes  the 
>   current  object  for  the  next designator (if any) to be that member.
>   The current object that results at the end of the designator list is
>   the subobject to be initialized by the following initializer.
>
> 33 EXAMPLE 9 Arrays  can  be  initialized  to  correspond  to  the 
>   elements  of  an  enumeration  by  using designators:
>
> ```
> enum { member_one, member_two };
> const char *nm[] = {
>     [member_two] = "member two",
>     [member_one] = "member one",
> };
> ```

EDIT:

Note that the syntax from the standard includes a `=` while OP's example does not.  The syntax without `=` is apparently an old syntax supported by GCC.  Compiling OP's example gives the following warning:

> warning: obsolete use of designated initializer without ‘=’

The [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html) states the following:

> An alternative syntax for this that has been obsolete since GCC 2.5 but GCC still accepts is to write ‘[index]’ before the element value, with no ‘=’.

Comment: The syntax without an equal sign is GNU specific.

Comment: That does not answer why the syntax in the question works. OP apparently is aware about the standard syntax.

Answer (score 3):

That's a [GNU extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html). It was standardized in C99 with slightly different syntax, namely an equal sign between the [index] and the value and no way to specify a range of indices. They are called *designated initializers*.

The C standard shows an example of probably the most widespread use, provide a string description for enums:

> **33   EXAMPLE 9**       Arrays can be initialized to correspond to the elements of an enumeration by using designators:

```
enum { member_one,           member_two };
const char *nm[] =           {
    [member_two]           = "member two",
    [member_one]           = "member one",
};
```

It even allows nifty stuff like

> **EXAMPLE 11** Designators can be used to provide explicit initialization when unadorned initializer lists might be misunderstood:

```
struct { int a[3], b; } w[] =
    { [0].a = {1}, [1].a[0] = 2 };
```

Comment: Mind linking to the documentation?

Comment: @CinCout, [C11 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) `6.7.9 Initialization`

Comment: I missed the lack of an equal sign. I revised the answer.